# What's the meaning of "get place"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the following sentence, belonging to Grammar for Pet book (unit 19):

> Your sisters may succeed in getting places at university

These sisters haven't attended yet a university, so did he say that they would have some job opportunities in the academic field (in a future), or they would have a brilliant experience in their studies (such as taking exams)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To **get a place at university** means that a university is willing to accept you as an undergraduate student. As you have more than one sister, they may **get places**- plural.

Note that the first word should probably be **your**, a possessive adjective which describes **sisters**, rather than **yours**, a possessive pronoun which would replace **sisters**:

> **Your** sisters may succeed in getting places at university - *possessive adjective*
> **Yours** may succeed in getting places at university - *possessive pronoun*

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question: I made a typo error by mistake

Comment: @JavaLatte I noticed a little typo, but I can't edit since It's just 1 character long not 6. "as **an** undergraduate" would be the correct way. I'm sure you just not noticed.

Comment: @AdriánJaramillo thanks for pointing that out: I fixed it.